# Can I filter OData resources by last updated date?

Tags: odata, wcf-data-services

Is it possible to query an OData collection filtering by the updated metadata field? The case for that would be to get a list of updates since the last check.

I've tried [http://odata.netflix.com/v1/Catalog/People?$filter=updated%20eq%202011-05-15T21:45:31Z](http://odata.netflix.com/v1/Catalog/People?%24filter=updated%20eq%202011-05-15T21:45:31Z), but it gives me "No property 'updated' exists in type 'Netflix.Catalog.Person' at position 0". Is there another way I can do this or reference the updated property in a filter statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updated element in the ATOM feed/entry representation may or may not contain actual data. Some services actually do store the real updated timestamp there, but some don't. Since the element is required to be present in all entries by the ATOM format, services which don't have the data to use there usually put some arbitrary timestamp as the value (by default WCF Data Services uses DateTime.Now for the updated field, which is what netflix service does as well).
The $filter can only reference real properties on a given entity. So if the service does have a property which contains the data backing the updated element you would need to find out the name of such property (in the $metadata for example) and then use that. If the service does not have a property like that (for example the netflix service doesn't), then there's no way to filter based on last updated timestamp, as there's no such thing in the underlying data store (the updated element is effectively a fake).
Also note that if you ask for JSON payload the updated element doesn't exist there and so only the real properties are present. Any query operators in the URL work only on the real properties.